# Sylius Some mandatory parameters are missing when trying to generate create's view

Tags: symfony, sylius

I have a related with product entity and need to have product's id in the url, like `/admin/products/{productId}/new-entity`. I'm struggling with the following error:

`An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Some mandatory parameters are missing ("productId") to generate a URL for route "app_admin_something_related_to_product_index".").` It's throwed when I click create's button. I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69045378/sylius-route-params-missing-on-redirect-syliusresourcebundle) a similar problem but the solution didn't help me. I finished with trying to overwrite some templates but they weren't applied. Does anyone kwon how can I handle it?

routes.yaml

```
app_admin_something_related_to_product:
    resource: |
    alias: app.something_related_to_product
    section: admin
    templates: "@SyliusAdmin\\Crud"
    grid: app_admin_something_related_to_product
    vars:
        all:
            subheader: xxx
        index:
            icon: ~
type: sylius.resource
prefix: /admin/products/{productId}
```

routes.yaml:

```
app_admin_something_related_to_product_create:
    path: /admin/products/{productId}/something-related-to-product/new
    methods: [GET, POST]
    defaults:
        _controller: app.controller.something_related_to_product:createAction
        _sylius:
            section: admin
            factory:
                method: createNew
                arguments:
                    - expr:notFoundOnNull(service('sylius.repository.product').find($productId))
            template: "@SyliusAdmin/Crud/create.html.twig"
            grid: app_admin_something_related_to_product
            redirect:
                route: app_admin_something_related_to_product_index
                parameters:
                    productId: $productId
                    parameters: { productId: $productId }
            permission: true
            vars:
                route:
                    parameters:
                        productId: $productId
                templates:
                    form: "@SyliusAdmin/ProductVariant/_form.html.twig"
                    breadcrumb: "@SyliusAdmin/ProductVariant/Create/_breadcrumb.html.twig"
                    header_title: "@SyliusAdmin/ProductVariant/Create/_headerTitle.html.twig"
```

_sylius.yaml

```
app_admin_something_related_to_product:
        driver:
            name: doctrine/orm
            options:
                class: App\Entity\xxx
                repository:
                    method: findByProduct
                    arguments: [$productId]
        fields:
            field1.name:
                type: string
                label: xxx
            field2.name:
                type: string
                label: xxx
            field3.name:
                type: string
                label: xxx
            field4.name:
                type: string
                label: xxx
        actions:
            main:
                create:
                    type: create
                    label: sylius.ui.create
                    options:
                        class: primary
                        icon: plus
                        header:
                            icon: cube
                            label: sylius.ui.type
                        label: app.ui.int_type
                        link:
                            route: app_admin_something_related_to_product_create
                            parameters:
                                productId: $productId
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/AdminBundle/Resources/config/routing/product_variant.yml` - it also has $productId as a route parameter, so that is a perfect example.

Also, take a look into `vendor/sylius/resource-bundle/src/Bundle/Routing/ResourceLoader.php` where parameters are taken to generate index/create/update/etc routes from `sylius.resource` type of route.

If you use both (listed in the post) routes at the same time, and get an exception when pressing Save, that means it can't generate URL to the index route (as ResourceController::createAction redirects you to `index` route by default). The reason is - you should add parameters to the index route like this:

```
app_admin_something_related_to_product:
    resource: |
    alias: app.something_related_to_product
    section: admin
    templates: "@SyliusAdmin\\Crud"
    grid: app_admin_something_related_to_product
    vars:
        all:
            subheader: xxx
        index:
            icon: ~
            route:
                parameters:
                    productId: $productId
    type: sylius.resource
    prefix: /admin/products/{productId}
```

Or like this:

```
app_admin_something_related_to_product:
    resource: |
    alias: app.something_related_to_product
    section: admin
    templates: "@SyliusAdmin\\Crud"
    grid: app_admin_something_related_to_product
    vars:
        route:
            parameters:
                productId: $productId
        all:
            subheader: xxx
        index:
            icon: ~
    type: sylius.resource
    prefix: /admin/products/{productId}
```